# How to fetch cabs location near by me using uber api

Tags: android, location, uber-api

I have created the RideParameters but I am unable to fetch cab details

```
RideParameters rideParams = new RideParameters.Builder()
      .setPickupLocation(37.775304, -122.417522, "Uber HQ", "1455 Market Street, San Francisco")
      .setDropoffLocation(37.795079, -122.4397805, "Embarcadero", "One Embarcadero Center, San Francisco")
      .setProductId("a1111c8c-c720-46c3-8534-2fcdd730040d")
      .build();
```

Comment: we are not get near by cab details because that worked based on your location lat and long,that not easy to get

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to fetch the exact location of nearby cabs. It is possible to get a time estimate for a product (taxi): https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/estimates-time-get